# Printer stops monthly Oracle Linux 8

Tags: linux, cups, printing, oracle-linux, printer

We got about 50 printers in our network. I've enabled the cups debug level to 2, but I still cannot see a clear reason for stoppage. We have CUPS Version 1.6.3 .

We have a workaround which is to restart the printer:
lpadmin -p myPrinter –E

cups error log:

```
d [29/Oct/2023:03:26:04 +0100] copy_attrs(to=0x55a87246f0c0, from=0x55a872193910, ra=0x55a8723e37a0, group=0, quickcopy=-2147483648)
D [29/Oct/2023:03:26:04 +0100] Returning IPP successful-ok for CUPS-Get-Printers (no URI) from localhost
d [29/Oct/2023:03:26:04 +0100] cupsdProcessIPPRequest: ippLength(response)=16376
d [29/Oct/2023:03:26:04 +0100] cupsdAddSelect(fd=15, read_cb=0x55a8713bbfa0, write_cb=0x55a8713bb880, data=0x55a8723f3260)
d [29/Oct/2023:03:26:04 +0100] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1698550925
d [29/Oct/2023:03:26:04 +0100] select_timeout(0): 301 seconds to timeout a client connection
d [29/Oct/2023:03:26:04 +0100] [Client 15] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=16376, response=0x55a87246f0c0(IPP_IDLE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [29/Oct/2023:03:26:04 +0100] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1698550925
d [29/Oct/2023:03:26:04 +0100] [Client 15] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=16368, response=0x55a87246f0c0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [29/Oct/2023:03:26:04 +0100] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1698550925
d [29/Oct/2023:03:26:04 +0100] [Client 15] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=16339, response=0x55a87246f0c0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [29/Oct/2023:03:26:04 +0100] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1698550925
d [29/Oct/2023:03:26:04 +0100] [Client 15] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=16302, response=0x55a87246f0c0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [29/Oct/2023:03:26:04 +0100] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1698550925
d [29/Oct/2023:03:26:04 +0100] [Client 15] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=16270, response=0x55a87246f0c0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [29/Oct/2023:03:26:04 +0100] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1698550925
d [29/Oct/2023:03:26:04 +0100] [Client 15] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=16248, response=0x55a87246f0c0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
d [29/Oct/2023:03:26:04 +0100] select_timeout: JobHistoryUpdate=1698550925
d [29/Oct/2023:03:26:04 +0100] [Client 15] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_POST_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODE_LENGTH, data_remaining=16223, response=0x55a87246f0c0(IPP_ATTRIBUTE), pipe_pid=0, file=-1
```

What else could I investigate further?